# Удаление пустых строк

Tags: php, строки

Как удалять много пустых строк в тексте, что-то типа `trim`, но функция другая, если есть?

Пример (сделано исходным кодом) -

[image: img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду пробельные символы (пробелы, перевода строки, табуляции)?

```
$str = '  abc de    fg ';
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
```

Comment: @romeo, не совсем. Переносы строк..

Comment: @ModaL И они тоже, я в скобках указал. Вы пробовали?
Возможно, у Вас в строке присутствуют ещё и теги, которые вполне могут производить перенос.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/(<br\/?>|\n)+/', '<br>', $str);
```

Comment: @KaZaца Без символа перевод каретки "\r\n" не получится.
Тогда уж лучше так:

    preg_replace('/(<br\/?>|\s)+/', '', $str);

Comment: Верно. Но так не лучше. Удалит все пробелы в тексте.

Answer (score -1):

```
$s = '<p>1111</p>
    <p>22222222 222222 2    22222<br></p>
    <p><br><br/></p>
    <br><br>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p><br>33 33 33</p>';

$s = preg_replace('@(?:\s+|<br\s*/?\s*>|<p>\s*(?:\s*<br\s*/?\s*>\s*)*\s*</p>|(<p>)\s*(?:\s*<br\s*/?\s*>\s*)+\s*|\s*(?:\s*<br\s*/?\s*>\s*)+\s*(</p>))@i', ' $1$2$3', $s);
$s == '<p>1111</p> <p>22222222 222222 2 22222 </p>             <p>33 33 33</p>'; // true
```

И да-да-да: негоже хэтмл регекспом парсить.

Comment: О_О омг. Для удаления многократных переносов вполне пойдет такая регулярка: 

    preg_replace("/(?:^\r\n|(\r\n)+)/", "$1", $text)

Comment: У него там разметка, а не просто переносы \r и \n